# Icon Color in Menu with Style

Tags: kotlin, icons, menuitem

I've looked a lot to see if I could style the color of the menu icon but I can't find one that shows in both standard and night themes. There are styling strings I can't access easily yet.

[image: The icon is shown below]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it in my notes from SO. This line:

```
android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
```

replaces the default line:

```
android:tint="#000000"
```

in the vector .xml file in the drawable directory. It also applies to the buttons on the toolbar supplied by the activity_main.xml file.

So now I see after downloading vector assets icons to look for this line.

And colorControlNormal is in the app's base style themes: one for the standard theme file themes.xml and one for the night/themes.xml file:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
```

So the icon shown in my original post is white. And I'll continue to add icons to the menu.

[image]